# link documents in sharepoint 2010

Tags: development, client-object-model, document, url

how can i create a link to a document in a library in c# using the object model in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: You tagged the client object model... Is it that object model of the full object model ?

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on what you mean by "create a link to a document"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitems.aspx) and [SPListItem.GetItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitems.aspx) will do the job. Note that SPListeItem has a ".URL" field.

The links have sample code that is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I would go with the following solution, if you are using the regular object model.  I can't tell if that it would work also with the client object model.

Use the Content Type "Link To a Document" and use the following code to make it work.  I had to do it for one of my projects, and it is definitely the way to go.

Check it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cliffgreen/creating-a-link-to-a-document-item-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically)